# Problem with FilesMatch not matching correctly

Tags: apache-2.2

We are having an issue with `FilesMatch`, it does not seem to be matching some file types. We are using the `FilesMatch` directive to allow me to add custom headers using mod_headers, config file details snippit below:

```
<FilesMatch  \.(list|dept|png|html|htm)>
Header set Last-Modified  "Mon, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
Header set Expires "Mon, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
Header set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>
```

We are using mod_jk to pass connections to Tomcat and the Struts to rename the files to .dept & .list ,etc.

The issue appears to be with matching the text/html files that are being served as files with .png (used in the regex match for sanity check) are matching fine.

Is there a specific file extension that I should be trying to match in apache when the files are being renamed with struts?

Comment: How is struts "renaming" the files? With a redirect? Or by reading a different filename? In other words, does the original requested URL contain a matching filetype?

Comment: Struts is renaming the file with a redirect

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to resolve the issue by using LocationMatch

```
<LocationMatch "\.(html|htm|shtml|shtm|txt|text)$" >
Header set Custom-Header1
....
</LocationMatch>
```